# How to fix syntax error in if form.is_valid():?

Tags: python, django

I'm having a Syntax error in `if form.is_valid():` and I don't know why.

```
form = ProductSort(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data["min_price"]:
            products = products.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data["min_price"])
    if form.cleaned_data["max_price"]:
            products = products.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data["max_price"])
```

Comment: is this how the code is indented? Because Python is an indentation-sensitive langauge, and the `form = ...` line should the have the same indetation as the `if form.is_valid` line.

Comment: you are missing `:` after `form = ProductSort(request.GET)`.

Comment: Plus you seem to have two rogue ` characters  in the fourth line.

Comment: There are some useful tools for code checking or reformat, such as: `white`, `flake8`, `autopep8`, `autoflake`

Comment: Is it syntax error or form.is_valid() returning False ?

Comment: if `request.GET` is empty, `form.is_valid()`will be `False`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#behavior-of-unbound-forms